# why classList gain better performance

Tags: javascript, html, performance

I've read the [G-plus post](https://plus.google.com/+PaulIrish/posts/APArpwWqew3) of Paul
It mainly switch `className` to `classList`'s API,while I know `className` will slow down cause the code touches the dom
And the question is why `classList` rocks? How does it work in a brief view ?